# Change the data pointer of OpenCV cv::Mat class object in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a question like the title.

what if I change the my_mat.data pointer to another pointer like below, is it fine?

```
unsigned char arr[100*3*20] = { 0, };

// initialization process
cv::Mat new_mat;
new_mat.create(20, 100, CV8UC3);

// operation to arr

new_mat.data = arr;
```

The above code works fine during long time.
I know the best way is deep copy to the "new_mat" but it is too slow.

Is this code fine?

Or, Is there any faster way to do it?

Comment: It's going to work but it's not recommended. `cv::Mat` is a just a "thin wrapper" that wraps the matrix data. In case `new_mat.data` already allocates memory for `data`, you are going to get a memory leak, because the memory is not de-allocated. It is more recommended to create `cv::Mat` after `arr` is ready. `cv::Mat new_mat(20, 100, CV8UC3, (void*)arr)`

Comment: And one more question. 
Then, If I initialize the cv::Mat class using input pointer like below:
cv::Mat new_mat(20, 100, CV8UC3, (void*)arr)
Is deep copy happend during the class generation, or just the data pointer of cv::Mat points the location of "arr"?

Comment: I've experimented and know that, If I create the cv::Mat with input pointer, then there is no deep copy happend. (cv::Mat new_mat(20, 100, CV8UC3, (void*)arr) ). the address of "arr" and "new_mat.data" are same.

Comment: You could have saved yourself experimentation by reading [the documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a51615ebf17a64c968df0bf49b4de6a3a), it explains that quite explicitly.

Comment: The conclusion: changing cv::Mat data to another data pointer (like my_mat.data = pointer_arr_u8) is fine. the cv::Mat is like a wrapper function (actually, returns smart pointer) and there is no memory leak. Its my conclusion. And if another guy have another question, then reply me.

Comment: no it's *not* fine. when the Mat is destroyed, it might try to delete that memory... because it *doesn't* know that it *doesn't own* the memory. it would still assume that *that* is memory it allocated earlier.